# Teach me on Telnet script

Tags: batch-file, telnet

Here is my situation. I am using a Motorola Canopy. Every time I shut down my PC or power off the modem, the ESN of my Canopy changes back from its default value.

I have been running `telnet` again and again on boot-up to have my Internet connection working. I want a batch file to do the job so that I don't have to run `telnet` again and again. I am using Windows 7 32-bit.

Here are the details:

- Canopy telnet is 169.254.1.1 (it has no password whatsoever)
- The ESN that I'm trying to place is db:68:d3

Manually I can do it using this script:

```
telnet 169.254.1.1
mac db:68:d3
```

and it's done..

If someone here can help me and make me this script it will be a great help. I have made a simple script here, but the problem is it stops on `telnet`:

```
cd \
rem .
COLOR 0E
@ECHO OFF
cls
ECHO Change ESN
pause
ECHO ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO PROCEED? 
pause
ECHO ARE YOU SURE?
pause
telnet 169.254.1.1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>after this the script below doesn't follow.
testing
enable
telnet+> mac db:68:d3
ECHO You have Changed ESN successfuly
ECHO Done.
Echo
```

Comment: Telnet grabs control of your terminal, so when you put the `telnet` command in your batch script, it expects input from your keyboard.

Comment: i see, my question is, is it possible to run that script?? or would you prefer me for other languages? like what?

Comment: Not possible to run that script. Easy to write in whatever language you want, you just need to open a socket to port 23 and send `mac db:68:d3`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it with bat files, but you can do it with windows scripting & vbscript, which should be also available by default. Save this as autoscript.wsf (.wsf is a [windows scripting file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File)):

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 169.254.1.1"
WshShell.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "mac db:68:d3"
WshShell.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Quit 
</script>
</job>
```

and call it from your bat file

```
call autoscript.wsf
```

or just run directly

```
C:\> autoscript.wsf
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick search shows that you could use putty and it's command line utility `plink` to get required result. You can get them here: [putty download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Put your commands in a file (eg.`myCommandFile.txt`):

```
mac db:68:d3
exit
```

You should be then able to run `plink 169.254.1.1 -telnet <myCommandFile.txt` from command line to set ESN you need.
I'm not sure if it will properly disconnect/terminate `plink`, you will have to test it with your setup.

After you confirm it works as expected put it in a batch file